# How to fix error on realloc of pointer of struct array?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc

I trying to realloc a dimension of an array of structure where there is one pointer. But i get some error on realloc.

```
 typedef struct {

    int userid;
    char username[40]; 
    char name[50]; 
    char surname[40];
    char sex;
    char email[50]; 
 } user;

 typedef struct {
        int numb_users;
    user* userslist;
 } info_users;


 int main() {
         info_users info_users;
     .......................
         //Before call "ManageUser" i call another function that do this -- > //THIS WORK 
         //info_users ->userslist = calloc( info_users ->numb_users, sizeof( user) );
         .................
         ManageUser( &info_users);
  }

  void ManageUser( info_users *info_users) {

         AddUser( info_users);
   }

   void AddUser(info_users *info_users) {

     info_users ->userslist = realloc(userslist->userslist, userslist->numb_users* sizeof( user) );

   }
```

How i solve the error on realloc?

Thanks

Comment: Typo? `realloc(info_users->userslist....` Also, it is usually helpful if you post the error messages.

Comment: I don't know, the only error that i get from debugger is this: "No source available for "realloc() at 0x76c58b62 or Break at address "0x76f8a5e1" with no debug information available, or outside of program code."

Comment: That sounds like a runtime error but the code you have here won't even compile. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `numb_users` seems to be unitialized when you call `realloc`. `calloc` will however set the memory content to zero.